# Can my recovery partition be used after upgrade?

Tags: windows, upgrade, hard-drive-recovery

I have an HP Pavilion laptop that came with Windows 8.1 pre-installed. I have not made a copy of recovery partition to DVD.

Now, if I upgrade it to Windows 10, will I be able to make recovery DVD/CD of Windows 8.1 after this?

Comment: If you want a Windows 8.1 recovery image, you should create it, before you perform the upgrade.

Answer (score 3):

"Note: If the manufacturer set up your PC to run from a compressed Windows image file (also known as Windows image file boot or WIMBoot) and included the option to **restore factory settings**, that option will no longer be available after you upgrade to Windows 10."

Found under "Can i go back to my old operating system"

[Microsoft Source](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/upgrade-faq-windows-10)

But if you made your HP recovery discs prior to upgrading to W10 you can use those to reinstall the previous operating system.

Comment: But how is the OEM recovery rendered useless, is it a change to the efi partition or MBR when you install/upgrade win10? Or is the recovery partition itself corrupted or deleted?

Comment: The link to the recovery partition is broken in the MBR or EFI, HP uses a custom MBR-EFI to make the recovery partition work (F11), it is overwritten when upgrading. The recovery partition remains intact, but cannot be accessed using the usual means, sometimes you can mark the recovery partition as Active in disk management and reboot, it may boot into HP recovery to recover to the original OS installed by HP

Comment: Would it be possible to replace the recovery boot sector (VBR) by installing grub to that partition. Then the new Windows boot manager might detect the partition as bootable upon install, or perhaps you'd have to install GRUB to the drive too. Of course F11 probably won't work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Once you upgrade to Windows 10, the recovery partition is also upgraded to Windows 10, so any recovery medium that you make will be Windows 10 recovery, not Windows 8.

1. If you wish to make a Windows 8 recovery disk before the Windows 10 install, you can use the options presented in the Recovery menu in the settings app.
2. If you wish to make a Windows 8 recovery disk after the Windows 10 install, you will need to download a Windows 8 recovery image (usually in ISO format).

Comment: I'm not sure this is true. Do you have a source to back this up? Recovery partitions are used to return the computer to the OEM state when it was new.

Comment: @CharlieRB When Windows 7 and 8.1 are clean installed, they automatically create recovery partitions. Windows 10 does not create recovery partitions when clean installed, but when a system with a pre-existing recovery partition is upgraded, then Windows 10 takes advantage of the recovery partition.

Comment: Actually, it appears that Microsoft has updated it's recovery policy. It seems that when Windows 7 and 8.1 are upgraded to Windows 10, the recovery partitions are permanently deleted/deactivated, so they are unusable.

Comment: I can not confirm this. Tried the repair options of a Lenovo notebook that had been updated from 8.1 to 10 and they failed as they tried to repair win 10  with files made for win 8.1. In this respect the recovery is now useless but still present. The reset to factory state option was the only one still operational and it restored "clean" win 8.1 on the system, which could subsequently be upgraded to win 10 in the normal way  because Microsoft already has the product key listed for win 10 due to the previous update. This again left the recovery partition untouched.