# How do I update my Windows recovery partition?

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, recovery-partition

I got a HP PC which came with Win8.1 Pro, updated to Win10 in last summer and again to 1511 TH2 2 months ago.
The recovery partition obviously contains the old Win8.1 wim image.

What is the preferred way to update it to the OS I use on the main partition?
Or simply delete and use USB in case of emergency?

(german language, Wiederherstellun=Recovery)

```
DISKPART> list part

 Partition ###  Typ               Größe    Offset
 -------------  ----------------  -------  -------
 Partition 1    Wiederherstellun  1023 MB  1024 KB
 Partition 2    System             360 MB  1024 MB
 Partition 3    Reserviert         128 MB  1384 MB
 Partition 4    Primär             226 GB  1512 MB
 Partition 5    Wiederherstellun   450 MB   227 GB
 Partition 6    Primär              10 GB   228 GB
```

edit:
If I try to use the built-in wizard "creaty recovery partiton", check "include system files", next, it does not find my (meanwhile) empty recovery partition with 10GB.

Comment: Honestly.  You don't need the recovery partition.  All you need to do is keep a Windows 10 installation media handy.  You have the ability to Reset Windows 10, which will reinstall Windows 10, if you need to solve any major problems on the current installation.

Comment: I believe I can answer this question but I need the partition names translated, and to know, which partition has the .wim file you want to change.  You have two recovery partitions, so I need to know, specifics in English.

Comment: @Ramhound part #6 had the .wim image. translate, no idea what en-US diskpart writes. It's often translated not 1:1 by MS. #6 also has OEM-partition attribute.

Comment: Partition 6 is probably created by the OEM to hold its installation files for hardware-specific drivers and pre-installed applications. It might be worth keeping, in case you want any of this software in the future. I don't know why you have two recovery partitions (1 and 5): maybe it was created by the Win10 installation. You can try a recovery, and abort before it does anything, but you'll see which system is configured for recovery. If you follow @Ramhound's advice, you can keep your installation disc up-to-date, and you can do more than simply return to the base OS with no other files.

Comment: You would be better of choosing a third-party program, that allows you to create your own recovery partition, then attempting to "update" the OEM partition.  As I point out there really isn't a need for the partition, you can install Windows 10 directly to the machine, and it will automatically activate.  The real solution would be create a.wim file from a clean installation of your current system ,with drivers installed, then create an installer media from that file.  But with your drivers online, no need for that, just keep a disk for the LAN/WLAN device and your golden.

Comment: Its worth pointing out the recovery partition in question was disabled, when you updated to Windows 10 anyways, so its not doing very much now anyways.  [This](http://superuser.com/questions/949926/can-my-recovery-partition-be-used-after-upgrade/949936#949936) answer goes into some more detail

Answer (score 1):

You don't need it anymore. Windows 10 has a reset option that restores your installation, optionally preserving certain files. In the worst case scenario where your Windows is corrupted and/or can't boot you might need the installation media to perform the reset.

If you are intent on having a restore solution without external media you can also try booting into the [Advanced Startup Options Menu](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2294-advanced-startup-options-boot-windows-10-a.html) (try using [F8](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/22455-f8-advanced-boot-options-enable-disable-windows-10-a.html)). Alternatively there should be third party tools to create backup partitions, but it seems the AOMEI option (mentioned earlier) is one of the few that advertises this feature.

Comment: can you link to some more info how win10 manage to reset itself or go back to an earlier snapshot **that differs** from Win8.1?

Comment: @FalcoAlexander It's called the reset option. http://windows.microsoft.com/en-hk/windows-10/windows-10-recovery-options It is not a downgrade. I think it uses the recovery partition created by windows 10 (not the boot partition). Though the actual restore image used might be inside the C: volume.